# Gradle 7.3 with Java 17 with task processIntTestResources: Entry [filename] is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set

Tags: java, gradle, java-17

I am trying to update a gradle 6.x version multi project application to gradle 7.3 as it is the first version to support Java 17. However, I am unable to progress past an issue arising from a task which is not declared in any of my `build.gradle` files. The error is below: ([] pieces are redacted)

```
Execution failed for task ':[root module]:[module]:processIntTestResources'.
> Entry [filename] is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy for details.
```

I think is associated with a sourceSet for integration tests, however, I never explicitly copy and files for those tests. I have also set all copy instructions to have this configuration with regard to duplicate handling:

```
duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
```

I also tried adding the above to projects which failed because that setting is only valid for Copy type tasks or blocks. I am by no means an expert in gradle and can add any relevant information needed, but I believe I have included what might be most relevant. I am really just looking for a direction I can head in to further debug this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show much about how you have integration tests configured, but I ran into a similar problem.  What saved me was this blog post by Tom Gregory:
[Running integration tests in Gradle](https://tomgregory.com/gradle-integration-tests/)

Since links can disappear, let me copy and paste the most important part that I found relevant, which is regarding the new (as of Gradle 7.3) [JVM Test Suite Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html) that adds support for integration tests. For me, this replaced my old integration test configuration:

```
testing {
    suites {
        integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) {
            dependencies {
                implementation project
            }
        }
    }
}
tasks.named('check') {
    dependsOn testing.suites.integrationTest
}
```

I also found the following useful, which is not in the above blog post, but is a leftover from my previous Gradle 6 configuration.  This for me duplicates the 'test' dependencies for 'integrationTest'.  This is not the recommended way of handling the test depedencies now (see the [JVM Test Suite Plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html)), but I still found it useful to get me back running quickly:

```
configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
```